# Define a variable in outer loop of Razor and use it inside the loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{ int i = 0;}
@foreach (var providerInfo in Model.Results)
{
    <div class="row">
      i = i + 1;
```

Inside the for-each loop I want to have a counter so I tried yo define my variable outside of it as above but Razor doesn't get it!   What is the correct Syntax to do this?

Comment: ok I think I should not have closed the block } when I define the int i  and use the same for for-each

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case statement `i = i + 1;` is currently interpreted as part of HTML. In order to tell Razor to interpret it as C# code, you can wrap your increment code with a `@{  }`:

```
@{ int i = 0;}
@foreach (var providerInfo in Model.Results)
{
    <div class="row">
      @{i = i + 1; }
}
```

Comment: was it wrong I combined the two blocks of code together under one @{ ?

Comment: @Bohn You can combine as many blocks of code inside `@{}` statement as required.